# How can I use Pytest with a local module not installed, without import errors

Tags: python, import, pytest

I've tried other solutions with no luck (`pytest.ini`, `__init__.py` inside `test\`, `conftest.py`...)

I have the following project structure:

```
.
├── module
│   ├── bar.py
│   ├── foo.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __main__.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_module.py
```

### Module works, test fails

and the files are:

`module/bar.py`:

```py
def bar():
    return "bar"
```

`module/foo.py`: *I suspect this import should be done in other way... * more on this later*

```py
from bar import bar

def foo():
    value = bar()
    print(value)
    return value
```

`module/__init__.py`:
empty

`module/__main__.py`:

```py
from foo import foo

foo()
```

And my module works, so if I call it:

```bash
python module
```

I get `bar`

so far so good.
Now the test, `tests/test_module.py`:

```py
from module import foo


def test_foo():
    assert foo.bar() == "bar"
```

`tests/__init__.py`:
empty

If I try to execute the tests, either with `pytest .` or `python -m pytest` I get

```
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_module.py __________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/susensio/Projects/sandbox/pytest/tests/test_module.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_module.py:1: in <module>
    from module import foo
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module'
```

So, at this point **module works, test does not**

---

### Module fails, test works

I've tried several things, the only one that changes something is the following:
changing `foo.py` to (note the relative import):

```py
from .bar import bar

def foo():
    value = bar()
    print(value)
    return value
```

causes the tests to work, but I cannot call the module with `python module`, it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/home/susensio/Projects/sandbox/pytest/module/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foo import foo
  File "/home/susensio/Projects/sandbox/pytest/module/foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .bar import bar
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

As I've said, other questions didn't help to solve this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time). You seem to be mixing up scripts vs modules and directories vs packages, as covered in the answers there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) mentioned by @brian61354270 the solution that worked was:

1. use relative imports as `from .bar import bar`. Now the test works but the code won't
2. **run the code with `-m` flag**. That seems to be the right approach. So, instead of doing `python module`, I should do `python -m module`. Now code and test both work!